# Unable to resize a SWT component (TextMergeViewer)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

Here is my problem : I have been using SWT to build a little GUI for an Eclise Plugin. On the picture below, the parts 1,2,2',3,3' behave exactly as I would like, and fit correctly in the window.

[image: Sample screenshot of what the GUI could look like]

However, the 4th part (which is a TextMergeViewer) keeps it little size in the corner of its container.

The following code shows how, for instance, I am defining the parts 2 and 2' :

```
    Composite viewersContainer;
    viewersContainer = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    viewersContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    viewersContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    data.heightHint = 400;
    data.widthHint = 400;

    oldFileViewer = new Browser(viewersContainer, SWT.BORDER);
    oldFileViewer.setText("here is the old file viewer\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    oldFileViewer.setLayoutData(data);

    newFileViewer = new Browser(viewersContainer, SWT.BORDER);
    newFileViewer.setText("and here is the new file viewer\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    newFileViewer.setLayoutData(data);
```

I tried to keep that model while creating the 4th part, with the following code :

```
    Composite c = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    GridData l = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false);
    c.setLayoutData(l);

    TextMergeViewerCreator tmvc = new TextMergeViewerCreator();

    TextMergeViewer tmv = null;

    tmv = (TextMergeViewer) tmvc.createViewer(c, new CompareConfiguration());


    DiffNode d = null;
    try {
        d = (DiffNode) (new CompareInput().prepareInput(new IProgressMonitor() {
            //Some overrided methods

            }
        }));
    } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    d.setDontExpand(false);
    tmv.setInput(d);
```

I guess that the DiffNode is not responsible on the TextMergeViewer file, but I cannot find what is wrong in my code.
Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `GridData` to the `Control` of `TextMergeViewer`:

```
tmv.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

---

Also, as a note: Do not reuse `GridData` objects. Each widget should have its own `GridData`.

[Reference](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridData.html):

> NOTE: **Do not reuse GridData objects**. Every control in a Composite that is managed by a GridLayout must have a unique GridData object.

Comment: It looks like a TextMergeViewer has no `setLayoutData` method

Comment: @MedAl Try calling it on the result of `getControl()`